# Automatic height setting for input tag

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having a dynamic input box, heigth of which need to be increaed based on the data adding. I tried to put new line after 10 characters in javascript but its not reflecting in input tag.

My code is

```
for(var i=0; i < field.length; i++)
  cityNameLength = cityNames.length;
  tempLength = cityNameLength;
  if(tempLength > 12)
  {
    tempLength = 0;
    cityNames+='\r\n';
  }
}
document.getElementById('val').value =cityNames ; // it is displaying everything in one line
```

and

```
<input type="text" id="val"/>
```

Comment: that is very humanly that he missed it here not in the actual code or else he would get error in compilation.

Answer (score 0):

For Multi Line you should use textarea tag.

Comment: cant i use input tag with height auto style ?

Comment: you can increase height but what i understand you need your text in multi lines for which you should use text area tag.